# How to pass an array as value to a single key in a hash of perl?

Tags: arrays, perl, hash, key-value

```
my %hash;
my @chain;
foreach (my $i=0; $i<=7; $i++)
{
    foreach (my $j=0; $j<=($#output); $j++)
    {
        if ($output[$j] =~ /chain1/)
        {
            push (@array, $output[$j]);
        }   
    }

    $hash{$chain[$i]} = [ @array ]; 
}

print "$hash{$chain[0]}\n";
```

The problem is I am not able to assign the arrays to unique keys in the hash. when I say print all the keys print the same output.

Comment: `foreach` is for elements, you are using it like a `for`.

Comment: Doesn't matter, `for` and `foreach` are entirely interchangeable.  (But it does look weird.)

Comment: Re "But it does look weird", Yeah. I'd use `for my $i (0..7)` if I wanted a counting loop, but `for my $chain (@chains)` and `for my $output (@outputs)` would be best here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You keep adding to the same array.

```
for (...) {
{
    my @array;                      <-- Add here

    for (...) {
        ...
        push @array, $output[$j];
        ...
    }

    $hash{$chain[$i]} = \@array;    <-- No need to copy elements anymore.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Perl hash are designed to hold only scalar values. It can have a key and the value can be the address reference of the array (which is scalar). But if the array value need to be modified concatenate the contents of the array as a string with certain delimiter and store the string as key.

Hope this Helps.